# Javascript regexp replace, multiline

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have some text content (read in from the HTML using jQuery) that looks like either of these examples:

```
<span>39.98</span><br />USD
```

or across multiple lines with an additional price, like:

```
<del>47.14</del>

    <span>39.98</span><br />USD
```

The numbers could be formatted like

- 1,234.99
- 1239,99
- 1 239,99

etc (i.e. not just a normal decimal number).  What I want to do is get just whatever value is inside the `<span></span>`.

This is what I've come up with so far, but I'm having problems with the multiline approach, and also the fact that there's potentially two numbers and I want to ignore the first one.  I've tried variations of using ^ and $, and the "m" multiline modifier, but no luck.

```
var strRegex = new RegExp(".*<span>(.*?)</span>.*", "g");

var strPrice = strContent.replace(strRegex, '$1');
```

I could use jQuery here if there's a way to target the span tag inside a string (i.e. it's not the DOM we're dealing with at this point).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using

```
"[\s\S]*<span>(.*?)</span>[\s\S]*"
```

instead of

```
".*<span>(.*?)</span>.*"
```

EDIT: since you're using a string to define your regex don't forget to esacpe your backslashes, so

```
[\s\S]
```

would be

```
[\\s\\S]
```

Comment: Good answers from all respondents, but yours was the closest to what I was trying to do, and it works nicely, thanks!

Comment: Why does the second character set [.\s\S] contain the . ?  It also seems to work with just [\s\S]

Comment: @duncan, that was a typo. fixing now.

Answer (score 2):

You could remove all line breaks from the string first and then run your regex:

```
strContent = strContent.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
var strRegex = new RegExp(".*<span>(.*?)</span>.*", "g");
var strPrice = strContent.replace(strRegex, '$1');
```

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty easy with jQuery. Simply wrap your HTML string inside a div and use jQuery as usual:

```
var myHTML = "<span>Span 1 HTML</span><span>Span 2 HTML</span><br />USD";
var $myHTML = $("<div>" + myHTML + "</div>");

$myHTML.find("span").each(function() {
   alert($(this).html()); 
});
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/u2ZN5/).

Answer (score 1):

You want this?

```
var str = "<span>39.98</span><br />USD\n<del>47.14</del>\n\n<span>40.00</span><br />USD";

var regex = /<span>([^<]*?)<\/span>/g;

var matches = str.match(regex);

for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++)
{
    document.write(matches[i]);
    document.write("<br>");
}
```

Test here: http://jsfiddle.net/9LQGK/

The `matches` array will contain the matches. But it isn't really clear what you want. What does `there's potentially two numbers and I want to ignore the first one` means?

Comment: I want the number in the <span></span>, but I don't want the number in the <del></del>